# Find the domain of the following function

Tags: functions

The given function is:

$f(x)=\sqrt{\log_{|x|-1}(x^2 + 4x +4)}$

My approach:

The argument $x^2+4x+4>0$ for all $x\neq-2$

Also, the base $|x|-1$ should be greater than 0 and not equal to 1.

$\therefore |x|-1>0$
$\implies |x|>1$
$\implies x>1$ or $x<-1$

And $|x|-1\neq1$

$\implies x\neq2,-2$

 Taking all this in consideration, my answer is $D_f= (-\infty,-2)\cup(-2,-1)\cup(1,\infty)$

However, the given answer is $(-\infty,-3]\cup(-2,-1)\cup(2,\infty)$

Where did I go wrong? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

My new approach:

**Case I:**
$0<|x|-1<1\implies 1<|x|<2$

Then, $x^2 + 4x+4\leq1\implies x^2+4x+3\leq0$

 or $-3\leq x\leq-1$

$\therefore x \in (-2,-1)$---(1)

**Case II:**
$|x|-1>1 \implies |x|>2$
Then, $x^2+4x+4\geq1 \implies x^2=4x+3\geq0$

or $x\geq-1 $ or $x\leq-3$

$\therefore x \in (-\infty,-3]\cup(2,\infty)$---(2)

From (1) and (2), $x\in(-\infty,-3]\cup(-2,-1)\cup(2,\infty)$

P.S.: Thanks @gimusi

Comment: I am dumb. I just saw that there was a root over the function. So, the argument has to be greater than the base. Nonetheless, please answer my question as I want to know the different methods to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Recall that

- for $a>1 \quad \log_a x \ge0 \iff x\ge 1$
- for $0<a<1 \quad \log_a x \ge 0 \iff 0<x\le 1$

therefore in order to have $\log_{|x|-1}(x^2 + 4x +4) \ge 0$ we need to consider two cases

- $|x|-1>1 \implies x^2 + 4x +4\ge 1$
- $0<|x|-1<1 \implies 0<x^2 + 4x +4\le 1$

Comment: Thanks. Now, I can proceed on my own

Comment: @Vaibhav That's nice! You are welcome. If you want show your work editing your own question I can take a look to it. Bye

Answer (score 0):

You need $\sqrt{\bullet}$ to be fed a positive real number, which you did not consider.